# Purpose of @relay(pattern:true)

Tags: relayjs

New expression `@relay(pattern: true)` was introduced in [change log](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for `relay.js` `0.5`.

But can't figure out from description nor tests what exactly it does and when I should use it when writing `fatQueries`.

Some example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a GraphQL query like the following:

```js
viewer {
  friends(first: 10) {
    totalCount
    edges { node { name } }
    pageInfo { hasNextPage }
  }
}
```

When defining a [fat query](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#the-fat-query) for a Relay mutation, to include the name of a field without specifying any of its subfields tells Relay that *any subfield of that field* could change as a result of that mutation.

Unfortunately, to omit connection arguments such as `find`, `first`, and `last` on the `friends` field will cause a validation error on the connection-argument-dependent fields `edges` and `pageInfo`:

```js
getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
    fragment on AddFriendMutationPayload {
      viewer { 
        friends { edges, pageInfo }  # Will throw the validation error below
      }
    }
  `;
}

// Uncaught Error: GraphQL validation/transform error ``You supplied the `pageInfo` 
// field on a connection named `friends`, but you did not supply an argument necessary 
// to do so. Use either the `find`, `first`, or `last` argument.`` in file 
// `/path/to/MyMutation.js`.
```

You can use the `@relay(pattern: true)` directive to indicate that want to use the fat query to **pattern match** against the tracked query, instead of to use it as a fully-fledged query.

```js
getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
    fragment on AddFriendMutationPayload @relay(pattern: true) {
      viewer {
        friends { edges, pageInfo }  # Valid!
      }
    }
  `;
}
```

For more information about mutations see: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#content

Comment: Hmmm... I thought this happened automatically. Quoting from the above doc link: `This fat query looks like any other GraphQL query, with one important distinction. We know some of these fields to be non-scalar (like friendEdge and friends) but notice that we have not named any of their children by way of a subquery. In this way, we indicate to Relay that anything under those non-scalar fields may change as a result of this mutation.`

Comment: Hunh. I wrote those docs too. I'm going to have to phone-a-friend on this one. @JoeSavona, what _is_ the pattern directive for?

Comment: Phoned a friend. Editing my answer!

Comment: We're going to have to update the mutations guide. https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/647

Comment: The answer to my previous question https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1300 and https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/1376