# Mutation not requesting for actively fetched container data in fatQuery on RANGE_ADD

Tags: relayjs

I am trying to do a `RANGE_ADD` mutation using what is now known as Relay Classic (this probably is resolved with Modern). I get the error:

`` Warning: writeRelayUpdatePayload(): Expected response payload to include the newly created edge `newThingEdge` and its `node` field. Did you forget to update the `RANGE_ADD` mutation config? ``

So, yes, the payload is not sending the anything more than the `clientMutationId` in the expected response shape because the request mutation is not asking for it.

According to @Joe Savona here, https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/521, this might be happening if there is no intersecting container requesting for this data. But that's not entirely true for me. My `Route` is requesting:

```
things: (Component) => Relay.QL`
    query {
      allThings(variable: $variable) {
        ${Component.getFragment('things')},
      }
    }
`,
```

while my fatQuery is requesting for:

```
fragment on AddMockThing {
  allThings(variable: "${variable}", first: 100) {
    edges { 
      node {
        id,
      },
    },
  },
  newThingEdge
}
```

Now you may say these aren't the same queries, because of the extra `first: 100` in the `getFatQuery` version, but if I don't use that, I get the error:

`Error: Error: You supplied the 'edges' field on a connection named 'allThings', but you did not supply an argument necessary to do so. Use either the 'find', 'first', or 'last' argument.`

On the other hand, if I add `first: 100` to the `Route` query, I get the error: `Error: Invalid root field 'allThings'; Relay only supports root fields with zero or one argument.`

Stuck between a fatQuery and a hard place. Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a validation error because the Relay compiler is looking for a connection argument (`first: X`). You can disable this particular validation by adding the `@relay(pattern: true)` directive. This marks the fat query as a ‘pattern’ to match against, rather than as something concrete.

```graphql
fragment on AddMockThing @relay(pattern: true) {
  allThings(variable: "${variable}") {
    edges { 
      node {
        id,
      },
    },
  },
  newThingEdge
}
```

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112045/802047

Comment: Thanks @steveluscher! It'll be a while before I jump back into that code to use your suggestion (and replace my workaround), so just wanted to acknowledge it for now.